# Combining CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, UPDATE TABLE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating a View in Postgresql in which I join multiple tables in one. I want to add a new variable with a timestamp at the end. I've done that with tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table
AS with table_temp AS (
 --joining tables
);

ALTER TABLE table
ADD COLUMN DateOfChange Timestamp;

UPDATE table
SET DateOfChange = LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) at TIME ZONE 'Etc/GMT+2';
```

I need to combine those sentences in one (due to the View).
I tried to create a table first, but I guess I'm doing it wrong. I did this:

```
CREATE TABLE table
AS UPDATE(
          ALTER TABLE(
               with table_temp AS (
                      --joining tables
               )
          ADD COLUMN DateOfChange Timestamp)
 SET DateOfChange = LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) at TIME ZONE 'Etc/GMT+2';
```

But this is not working. How to do it correctly? Is it possible to make such a view?

Comment: Do you simply want a column default value?

Comment: Tables/Views are being rewritten automatically, so column values will change. So, it is not really the default value...

Comment: select .. ,   LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) at TIME ZONE 'Etc/GMT+2' as  DateOfChange from --joining tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET TIME ZONE 'Etc/GMT+2';
CREATE VIEW <view_name> AS
       SELECT <your_fields>,DateOfChange Timestamp TIME ZONE DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) 
       FROM <your_tables_joined_as_needed>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) for that:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view AS 
    SELECT <table columns>, LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) AS date_of_change FROM table1
UNION (
    SELECT <table columns>, LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) AS date_of_change FROM table2
);
```

The materialized view works like a combination of a table (storage) and views (fetched values). Once you have created this view, you can easily update the data via

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view;
```